# Is there a way to selectively, automatically refuse to respond to an email "receipt" request in Outlook 2003?

Tags: windows-xp, microsoft-outlook-2003

XP3 Pro
Outlook 2003

Various persons wish an acknowledgement to emails they have sent, even if it is the most trivial. I would like to set up a permanent refusal to these requests, but selectively, by person.

Is there a way to selectively, automatically cancel responses to an email "receipt" message in Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, unfortunately there isn't an official way to do this in any version of outlook